# How to put the authorization in hadoop 2.5 on the web interface 8088, 50070 (50075)?

Tags: hadoop

How can we secure access via the login / password to the web interface in hadoop on ports 8088 and 50070, in order to hide hdfs, found parameters hadoop.http.authentication.* In the core-default.xml but not understand them, there the right decision?

Version of hadoop 2.5.2, himself new to hadoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can secure the hadoop with kerberos security. Read [SecureMode](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html) documentation. Read [this](http://mapredit.blogspot.in/2012/10/secure-your-cluster-with-kerberos.html) blog for understanding how to enable security. Here getting started with [Kerberos](http://blog.manula.org/2012/04/setting-up-kerberos-server-with-debian.html)

Comment: i think to use basic auth